Нет прав на запись в директорию на линуксе
У меня запущен проект на линуксе, но файловый сервис не может записывать файлы в директорию data, не хватает прав. Я проставил права на чтение и запись рекурсивно: sudo chmod -R +rw ./data, но запись в дату все равно не работает. Кроме того, я не могу даже скопировать книгу или любой другой файл в эту директорию - нет прав. Вот свойства директории:

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 20 15:16 data

Что я делаю не так? Как дать права на запись в эту директорию? Не работает даже chmod 777

Обычно для сервисов создают отдельного пользователя, и рабочей папке его назначают владельцем (chown)

Как / через что этот сервис запущен? Какой дистрибутив?

Сервис запущен в idea, база данных в докере, дистрибутив убунту

«в idea» — то есть не от имени root? Ну тогда всё логично, на показанных вами свойствах data чётко видно, что другие пользователи не имеют прав на запись (и на них же чётко видно, что никакого chmod 777 вы не сделали)

acl включайте и давайте права по пользователям раз бардак развели

@andreymal, согласен


drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 20 15:16 data

свойства директории, означает:
data - это директория, владелец и группа этой директории - root.
  Владелец root, может переходить в эту директорию и читать содержимое этой директории, а так же создавать, редактировать и удалять файлы.   Члены группы root, могут переходить и читать содержимое этой директории.
Остальные пользователи, могут переходить и читать содержимое этой директории.


Что я делаю не так?


Неизвестно.


Как дать права на запись в эту директорию?


смотря кому (пользователь root может создавать, редактировать и удалять файлы.)

